# Pass a function with parameters to a VoidCallback in class constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class `RedditArtReward` that passes a taphandler to another class `RedditPixels`. `RedditArtReward` implementation below:

```
class RedditArtReward extends StatefulWidget {
  const RedditArtReward({super.key});
  @override
  State<RedditArtReward> createState() => _RedditArtRewardState();
}

class _RedditArtRewardState extends State<RedditArtReward> {
  int matrixSize = 9;
  late List<List<Color>> pixelColorMatrix = getAlmostRandomMatrix(matrixSize);
  // this function is used to generate a random size x size matrix with 3 colors
  getAlmostRandomMatrix(size) {
    makeMatrix() => Iterable<List<Color>>.generate(
        size, (i) => List<Color>.filled(size, Colors.red)).toList();
    List<List<Color>> matrix =
        makeMatrix(); //size x size matrix with red default
    return matrix;
  }

  void handleTap() {
    setState(() {
      pixelColorMatrix[0][0] = Colors.transparent;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: Padding(
          padding:
              const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 80, right: 10, bottom: 0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              RedditPixels(pixelColorMatrix, matrixSize, handleTap),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`RedditPixels` implementation below:

```
class RedditPixels extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<List<Color>> matrix;
  final int size;
  final VoidCallback tapHandler;
  const RedditPixels(this.matrix, this.size, this.tapHandler, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          Column(children: [
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
              Row(
                children: [
                  for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) ...[
                    LayoutBuilder(
                      builder: (context, constraints) {
                        return Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                          child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: tapHandler,
                              child: Container(
                                width: 40,
                                height: 35,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: matrix[i][j],
                                    border: Border.all(
                                        width: 1, color: Colors.white)),
                              )),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ]
                ],
              )
          ]),
        ]));
  }
}
```

In the `onTap` i want to pass the value of i and j to find out which element was clicked. is there a way to pass these values from the `onTap` to the `handleTap` function?
I tried replacing `final VoidCallback tapHandler;` to use `Function(int, int)` but failed with errors.

> The following assertion was thrown building LayoutBuilder: setState()
> or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For passing value, the function will be

```dart
  final Function(int i, int j) tapHandler;
```

And call this function

```
child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => tapHandler(i, j),
```

And use case on `RedditArtReward`

```dart
RedditPixels(pixelColorMatrix, matrixSize, (i, j) {
  setState(() {
    pixelColorMatrix[i][j] = Colors.transparent;
  });
}),
```

Also, you may prefer named argument instead of positional.

Comment: Modified definition  to `final Function(int i, int j) tapHandler;`, tap action to `onTap: tapHandler(i, j),` and  `void handleTap(int i, int j) { setState(() { pixelColorMatrix[i][j] = Colors.transparent; }); }` still getting the same error

Comment: forgot to include and `onTap: () => tapHandler(i, j),`

Comment: Thank you so much. You are a saviour. i am new to flutter, so not exactly familiar with all the syntax <3

Comment: glad to help, you can find more about [dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour)

Comment: That's a lot of stuff to read. I know most of it but not all the syntax.